# Unexplained operator precedence in SQL Server pad right script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

As part of a request to generate a zero padded unique identifer I created what I thought would be a simple statement

```
right('00000000' + convert(char(6),ID),6)
```

However, this did not turn out as zero padded characters at all.
Further investigation reveals all is not as I would have expected.
See:

```
drop table #test 
go
select --top 30
    right('00000000' + convert(varchar(6),ID),6) varcharPadRight, --results in varchar(6) in tempdb
    right('00000000' + convert(char(6),ID),6) charPadRight, --results in varchar(6) in tempdb
    right('00000000' + convert(char(6),ID),20) charPadRight20, --results in varchar(14) in tempdb
    right('00000000' + convert(varchar(6),ID),20) vcharPadRight20 --results in varchar(14) in tempdb
into #test
from requestidentifier aTableWithAnIntIdentityColumn
where aTableWithAnIntIdentityColumn.ID in (1,100,1000)
go
select * from #test

select left(so.name, 5) name,sc.name, sc.xtype, sc.length from tempdb..sysobjects so inner join tempdb..syscolumns sc on so.id = sc.id where so.name like '%test%'
```

The results of this are:

```
varcharPadRight charPadRight charPadRight20 vcharPadRight20
--------------- ------------ -------------- ---------------
000100          100          00000000100    00000000100
001000          1000         000000001000   000000001000
000001          1            000000001      000000001
```

and

```
tableName colName        xtype length
--------- -------------- ----- ------
#test     varcharPadRigh 167   6
#test     charPadRight   167   6
#test     charPadRight20 167   14
#test     vcharPadRight2 167   14
```

Where an xtype of 167 is a varchar.

Is there anybody that can explain the ordering of the operations that would cause these (to me) unexpected results?

(This behaviour is consistent in SQL Server 2005 and 2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple explanation is that the char data type has spaces on the right to make it the length of the variable.  So, if you have a char(6) and set it to '3' the value in the variable will actually be 3-space-space-space-space-space.  That's a 3 followed by 5 spaces to make the total length = 6 characters.

When you add 6 zero's to the left of the string, SQL is doing some data type conversions.  Hard coding a string will result in a varchar, so '000000' will have the data type varchar(6).  When you append a char and a varchar, the result is a varchar with the lengths combined.

```
'000000' + Convert(Char(6), int)
VarChar(6) + Char(6)
varchar(12)
```

The Char(6) part will still have the spaces padded on the right of the data, so when you take the 6 right most characters, you are getting the spaces.

varchar doesn't pad with spaces on the end so it works exactly as you would expect it to.

PROOF:

```
Declare @ID Int
Set @Id = 3

-- Data type after converting to char (results in char(6))
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(Convert(Char(6), @id), 'BaseType') As DatType, 
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(Convert(Char(6), @id), 'MaxLength') As Length,
       Convert(Char(6), @id)

-- data type of hard coded string (Results in varchar(6))
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY('000000', 'BaseType') As DatType, 
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY('000000', 'MaxLength') As Length,
       '000000'

-- data type of varchar concatenate char (Results in varchar(12))
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY('000000' + Convert(Char(6), @id), 'BaseType') As DataType,
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY('000000' + Convert(Char(6), @id), 'MaxLength') As Length,
       '000000' + Convert(Char(6), @id)

-- data type of the result (results in varchar(6))
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(Right('000000' + Convert(Char(6), @id), 6), 'BaseType') As DataType,
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(Right('000000' + Convert(Char(6), @id), 6), 'MaxLength') As Length,
       Right('000000' + Convert(Char(6), @id), 6)
```

Comment: Cheers SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY a *lot* better than tempdb hacking.

Answer (score 1):

Converting an int to a char(6) is left aligned, so

```
   int -> char(6) -> '000' + char(6) -> right('000' + char(6))
    1  -> 1______ -> '0001_____'     -> '1_____'
    10 -> 10_____ -> '00010____'     -> '10____'
    etc
```

Thus an rtrim into the code will give the expected results
e.g.

```
right('00000000' + rtrim(convert(char(6),ID)),6)
```

Comment: Just using `varchar()` instead of `char()` seems by far the most sensible thing to do though - it avoids adding the padding characters in the first place.

Comment: @Andriy M - possibly, but I was confused, since the OP seems to be aware that `varchar()` works (as per their first example), so I thought I might be missing something.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of varchar fixing it, just wanted to understand why.